# getting all current users of your kivy app to display on a single screen

Tags: kivy

I'm new to Stackoverflow, and new to programming. i have been learning the basics of python for the last 5 months. for the last 2 weeks i started learning kivy mainly thru the [kivy crash course tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjmsP33prLPAhVD1h4KHf4LBK4QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Finclem.net%2Fpages%2Fkivy-crash-course%2F&usg=AFQjCNGwfq9EHb-R_4bvWazx-uXb55OHJA&sig2=MdHOcH-wqXKtoK05nhZl3g). 
I am trying to make a simple app for my own education. what i want for my app is a login screen. once someone login, the next screen should be a screen listing  all the users (each on a button). here is a code example of what i want for the second screen to look like. Notice that in the code below,  i am iterating through range(10). instead of doing this, i want to iterate through a list of login users and displaying it on a button.

so here is my questions: how do you create such a list? for example if the app is downloaded by 2 users and they both sign in, i want to be able to display both users on the second screen of the app on both phone.
do i need some type of online storage system to do this?

here is a [login example](https://gist.github.com/Cheaterman/812203a74f8c552a4918) that i am trying to modify to fit my need.
i searched the web but could find any information about doing this.

sorry if this is not posted on the right section.
Thanks

```
def build(self):
    layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
    layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
    for i in range(10):
        btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=80)
        layout.add_widget(btn)
    root = ScrollView()
    root.add_widget(layout)
    return root
```

if **name**=='**main**':
     Scroll().run()

Answer (score 0):

If people are going to download your App and login to it, then you should have a webserver with controllers and a working database for adding and retrieving users. So first create your webserver using any framework or tool you want (I sugget Turbogerars http://turbogears.readthedocs.io/ based on my own experience). Then you should implement your login and sign-up pages in your kivy app. Then in your webserver, define a controller that returns the list of registered users. then in your kivy app you can iterate through that list and create buttons.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I was also researching the web on how to do it. I discovered a database called redis. I signed up for an account and was able to store some info and read from it.   import redis

r = redis.Redis(
    host='myaccount.cloud.redislabs.com',
    port=13243, 
    password='xxxxxx')
r.set('name', 'Emmanuel')
value = r.get('name')
print value

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I was also researching the web on how to do it. I discovered a database called redis. I signed up for an account and was able to store some info and read from it. so i was planning on storing the users info on the redis database and read from it when needed. i may be thinking incorrectly about this. If you are familiar with the redis db please let me know what you think. i have also visited the website you provided in your answer. how complex is it to build a website server as i have never done one before? do you think it is doable for a newbie? thanks

Comment: yes I am familiarr with redis. Yes it is possible but it might take some time if you are new to this. do you mean you are using redis on a server and clients get their data from your redis database?